# Is "install" a shortcut for cp + chown + chmod, or does it do more?

Tags: software-installation, file-copy, chmod, chown

I read `man install`, and it seems that it just copies files with ownership & mode. So, is `install` a shortcut for `cp` + `chown` + `chmod`, or does it do more, under the hood?

Comment: It does exactly what the man page says it does.

Comment: Given this, you almost certainly did not read [`man install`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=install) or [`man install`](https://illumos.org/man/1m/install).

Comment: @JdeBP It is *because* I read `man install` that I was hesitating if there are benefits of using it vs. using cp chown chmod.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `$ which install` tells you that it is a shell built-in, `install` shouldn't be some sort of wrapper to `cp` + `chown` + `chmod`.

The `man` page reveals that GNU `install` has a few extra options, like `-s`, which strips symbol tables to save space. I'm not sure that this can easily be achieved with `cp` + `chown` + `chmod`, as this doesn't seem to be mentioned on any of their `man` pages.

Comment: To replicate `-s` you need to run `strip`, it’s not something `cp`/`chown`/`chmod` can do.

Comment: There are a lot more differences than even that.  Don't forget the `-d` option, and its subtle difference to `mkdir -p`.  Then with BSD `install` there are atomic copying, all of the `mtree`-related functionality, and the various link-instead-of-copy modes.